# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1059, "Identifier name is too long")

Tags: flask, sqlacodegen

I got this error when I tried to inspect db that I created before.

And I used this below command to make existing table as models.py file.

```
flask-sqlacodegen "mysql+pymysql://[DBUser]:[DBPassword]@[DBhost]:3306/[TableName]" > models.py
```

Is there any idea about this problem?
And how to make models.py file with already existing database in flask?

Please give me any suggestions to solve this problem.